# Kafka connect transformers are applied before or after connect converters

Tags: apache-kafka, xml-parsing, jaxb, apache-kafka-connect

Hi I am trying to understand the flow of kafka connect transformers and converters.

I am using fileStream source connector with xml transformers to enforce schema from xsd. When I am using converter as string I am able to parse the message but in kafka it is coming like
`Struct={Struct={name,abcd}` in string.
But I tried to change the converter to jsonConverter i am not able to parse xml getting error.

Trying to understand how transformers and converters sequence work at Source connector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For source connectors, transforms are applied after reading the data, and before data is serialized using the Converter.

For sink connectors, transforms are after the Converter deserializes from Kafka, but before writing to the Sink destination.

Better way to think about it - Connect Struct/Schema objects are what are being serialized. Source connectors define a Schema of the upstream data and Sink connectors extract that data into a format they understand. In-between Kafka and the Converters, all data is stored as bytes on the Kafka topic.

[image]

> tried to change the converter to jsonConverter i am not able to parse xml

Probably because XML isn't JSON, and vice-versa...